# Oracle Apex is generating a simple query that takes a long time to execute

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an iterative report, and pagination was enabled, which resulted in a query taking 16 seconds to finish. I read some information about it

[text](http://web.archive.org/web/20170706183715/http://rwijk.blogspot.ca/2016/11/performance-aspects-of-apex-reports.html)

and disabled pagination and the maximum number of returnable rows. Now, the query generated in Apex is very fast in PL/SQL. The problem is that it still takes a long time on the web. I used the debugger, and it's still taking 16 seconds. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

My original query.

```
SELECT '' Link,
       C.CHA_IN_CODIGO "Cod",
       C.CHA_ST_ASSUNTO "Assunto",
       C.CHA_DT_ABERTURA "Dt Abertura",
       C.CHA_ST_STATUS "Status",
       C.CHA_ST_TIPO "Tipo",
       U.USU_ST_NOME "Solicitante",
       CA.CAT_ST_DESCRICAO "Categoria",
       L.ORF_ST_DESCRICAO "Localização"
       

  FROM INF_CHAMADOS C

 INNER JOIN GLO_USUARIO U
    ON U.USU_IN_CODIGO = C.USU_IN_CODIGO

 INNER JOIN GLO_VW_LOCALIZACAO L
    ON L.ORF_IN_REDUZIDO = C.CHA_IN_LOCALIZACAO

 INNER JOIN INF_CHAMADOS_CATEGORIA CA
    ON CA.CAT_IN_CODIGO = C.CHA_IN_CATEGORIA

 WHERE (1 = 1
   AND C.CHA_ST_STATUS = 'Fechado'
   AND C.USU_IN_CODIGO = :COD_USUARIO) 
   OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM INF_CHAMADOS_OBSERVADOR O
         WHERE O.CHA_IN_CODIGO = C.CHA_IN_CODIGO
           AND O.USU_IN_CODIGO = :COD_USUARIO
           AND C.CHA_ST_STATUS = 'Fechado')
)
```

In plsql 0,097 seconds

I tried removing the pagination and putting null in the maximum number of returnable lines.

Code generated by Apex obtained in the debugger and taking 16 seconds to execute.

```
 select i.*
 from (select "LINK","Cod","Assunto","Dt Abertura","Status","Tipo","Solicitante","Categoria","Localização"
from(select /*+ qb_name(apex$inner) */d."LINK",d."Cod",d."Assunto",d."Dt Abertura",d."Status",d."Tipo",d."Solicitante",d."Categoria",d."Localização" from(SELECT '' Link,
       C.CHA_IN_CODIGO "Cod",
       C.CHA_ST_ASSUNTO "Assunto",
       C.CHA_DT_ABERTURA "Dt Abertura",
       C.CHA_ST_STATUS "Status",
       C.CHA_ST_TIPO "Tipo",
       U.USU_ST_NOME "Solicitante",
       CA.CAT_ST_DESCRICAO "Categoria",
       L.ORF_ST_DESCRICAO "Localização"
       --C.CHA_ST_DESCRICAO "Descrição" -- Causa lentidão

  FROM INF_CHAMADOS C

 INNER JOIN GLO_USUARIO U
    ON U.USU_IN_CODIGO = C.USU_IN_CODIGO

 INNER JOIN GLO_VW_LOCALIZACAO L
    ON L.ORF_IN_REDUZIDO = C.CHA_IN_LOCALIZACAO

 INNER JOIN INF_CHAMADOS_CATEGORIA CA
    ON CA.CAT_IN_CODIGO = C.CHA_IN_CATEGORIA

 WHERE (1 = 1
   AND C.CHA_ST_STATUS = 'Fechado'
   AND C.USU_IN_CODIGO = v('COD_USUARIO')) 
   OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM INF_CHAMADOS_OBSERVADOR O
         WHERE O.CHA_IN_CODIGO = C.CHA_IN_CODIGO
           AND O.USU_IN_CODIGO = v('COD_USUARIO')
           AND C.CHA_ST_STATUS = 'Fechado')
)
)d
 )i 

)i where 1=1
```

Comment: Try eliminating the use of `exists()` by expressing it as a join

Comment: @Bohemian Worked perfectly. I didn't understand why, because in plsql the time with exists and left join were the same. You know why?

Answer (score 0):

That article you are referring to is 8 years old.... it dates from apex 5. A lot has changed since then - in Apex 18 (5 years ago ;) ). I'd suggest going through [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/application-express-18-and-report-pagination) blog and checking if that helps you in any way.

**Summary**:
*Since APEX 18.2 the developer can control how pagination is executed: APEX provides two "pseudo hints": APEX$USE_ROWNUM_PAGINATION and APEX$USE_NO_PAGINATION. These pseudo hints are only recognized by APEX and must be placed into the Optimizer Hint region attribute in page designer.*